# MongoDB Lack of performace on $group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working on a project where a user can place bets about a match and then earns points if he has bet for the winning team.

I'm building a leaderboard where I need to choose the 50 best players on the platform (those who have the most points).

Processing points dynamically compelled me to look at the aggregate method in order to calculate the user points from these `Models`:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  admin: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  username: String,
  password: String,
  pronos: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Prono', default: [] }],
});

const PronoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  match: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Match' },
  local: Number,
  guest: Number,
  coeff: Number,
});

const StepSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  matchs: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Match', default: [] }],
  name: String,
});

const CompetitionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  steps: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Step', default: [] }],
  start: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date },
  name: String,
});

const MatchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  local: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' },
  guest: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' },
  localScore: { type: Number, default: -1 },
  guestScore: { type: Number, default: -1 },
  date: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date },
});
```

To sum up all these code:

A player places bets, called `pronos` on `Matches` that are inside `Steps`, them being inside a `Competition`. So every steps of the competition has its matches.

I've been producing this to calculate the points for the players and I would like to know if I'm heading to the right direction:

```js
  const users = await User.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$pronos' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'pronos',
        localField: 'pronos',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'pronoObjects',
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$pronoObjects' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'matches',
        localField: 'pronoObjects.match',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'matches',
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$matches' },
    {
      $addFields: {
        pointsEarned: {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $eq: ['$pronoObjects.local', '$matches.localScore'] },
                    { $eq: ['$pronoObjects.guest', '$matches.guestScore'] },
                  ],
                },
                then: 3,
              },
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $lt: [{ $subtract: ['$pronoObjects.local', '$pronoObjects.guest'] }, 0] },
                    { $lt: [{ $subtract: ['$matches.localScore', '$matches.guestScore'] }, 0] }
                  ]
                },
                then: 1,
              },
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $gt: [{ $subtract: ['$pronoObjects.local', '$pronoObjects.guest'] }, 0] },
                    { $gt: [{ $subtract: ['$matches.localScore', '$matches.guestScore'] }, 0] }
                  ]
                },
                then: 1,
              },
            ],
            default: 0,
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        points: { $sum: '$pointsEarned' }
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user',
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Since it's working the way I want, I planned to build up a ranking by `Competition`, where a user can select a competition ID and see the ranking for it.

When trying to achieve that, I've been using so many unwind methods that my response was 10k lines long before grouping. Thus I would like to know if anyone can hint me about the right way to achieve this.

I'm not looking for the complete answer, I'm new to mongo and would like to know about good practices or learn new aggregation methods.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I managed to get the points for every user with this aggregation. The problem is that it takes more than 10 seconds to run over 400 matches with only 2 users.
Am I missing something ?

Here is the request I use:

```js
  return await Competition.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: ['$_id', { $toObjectId: compId }],
        }
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$steps' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'steps',
        as: 'stepsObject',
        localField: 'steps',
        foreignField: '_id',
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$stepsObject' },
    { $unwind: '$stepsObject.matchs' },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        stepsObject: 1,
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'matches',
        as: 'matchesObject',
        let: { otherid: '$stepsObject.matchs' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: ['$$otherid', '$_id'] },
                  { $ne: ['$localScore', -1] },
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    },
    { $unwind: '$matchesObject' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        as: 'users',
        pipeline: [
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              pronos: 1,
            }
          }
        ],
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$users' },
    { $unwind: '$users.pronos' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'pronos',
        as: 'pronosObject',
        let: { matchid: '$matchesObject._id', knownpronos: '$users.pronos' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr:
              {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: ['$$matchid', '$match'], },
                  { $eq: ['$$knownpronos', '$_id'] },
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
        // localField: 'users.pronos',
        // foreignField: '_id',
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$pronosObject' },
    {
      $addFields: {
        pointsEarned: {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $eq: ['$pronosObject.local', '$matchesObject.localScore'] },
                    { $eq: ['$pronosObject.guest', '$matchesObject.guestScore'] },
                  ],
                },
                then: { $multiply: [3, '$pronosObject.coeff'] },
              },
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $lt: [{ $subtract: ['$pronosObject.local', '$pronosObject.guest'] }, 0] },
                    { $lt: [{ $subtract: ['$matchesObject.localScore', '$matchesObject.guestScore'] }, 0] }
                  ]
                },
                then: { $multiply: [1, '$pronosObject.coeff'] },
              },
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $gt: [{ $subtract: ['$pronosObject.local', '$pronosObject.guest'] }, 0] },
                    { $gt: [{ $subtract: ['$matchesObject.localScore', '$matchesObject.guestScore'] }, 0] }
                  ]
                },
                then: { $multiply: [1, '$pronosObject.coeff'] },
              },
            ],
            default: 0,
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$users._id',
        pointsEarned: { $sum: '$pointsEarned' },
      }
    }
  ]);
```

EDIT 2:

I rewrote the entire pipeline with a different approach much faster. I still have a tiny problem. If I get rid of the final group, the request only take 4 milliseconds to run, but the final group to group points by id takes it up to 550ms. I don't know how can I optimize this since it's the final addition of all points for every user.

Here is what I came with:

```js
  return await Competition.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: ['$_id', { $toObjectId: compId }],
        }
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$steps' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'steps',
        as: 'stepsObject',
        localField: 'steps',
        foreignField: '_id',
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$stepsObject' },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        stepsObject: 1,
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'matches',
        as: 'matchesObject',
        let: { otherid: '$stepsObject.matchs' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $in: ['$_id', '$$otherid'] },
                  { $ne: ['$localScore', -1] },
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        as: 'users',
        pipeline: [
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              pronos: 1,
            }
          }
        ],
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$users' },
    { $unwind: '$users.pronos' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'pronos',
        as: 'pronosObject',
        localField: 'users.pronos',
        foreignField: '_id',
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$pronosObject' },
    {
      $project: {
        user_id: '$users._id',
        pronosObject: 1,
        matchesObjects: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $filter: {
                input: '$matchesObject',
                as: 'matchesObjects',
                cond: { $eq: ['$$matchesObjects._id', '$pronosObject.match'] }
              }
            }, 0
          ]
        },
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        pointsEarned: {
          $switch: {
            branches: [
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $eq: ['$pronosObject.local', '$matchesObjects.localScore'] },
                    { $eq: ['$pronosObject.guest', '$matchesObjects.guestScore'] },
                  ],
                },
                then: { $multiply: [3, '$pronosObject.coeff'] },
              },
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $lt: [{ $subtract: ['$pronosObject.local', '$pronosObject.guest'] }, 0] },
                    { $lt: [{ $subtract: ['$matchesObjects.localScore', '$matchesObjects.guestScore'] }, 0] }
                  ]
                },
                then: { $multiply: [1, '$pronosObject.coeff'] },
              },
              {
                case: {
                  $and: [
                    { $gt: [{ $subtract: ['$pronosObject.local', '$pronosObject.guest'] }, 0] },
                    { $gt: [{ $subtract: ['$matchesObjects.localScore', '$matchesObjects.guestScore'] }, 0] }
                  ]
                },
                then: { $multiply: [1, '$pronosObject.coeff'] },
              },
            ],
            default: 0,
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: { // This is causing me trouble
        _id: '$user_id',
        pointsEarned: { $sum: '$pointsEarned' },
      }
    }
  ]);
```